# Connect to Oracle 11g using VS2010.net Drivers/Cleints

Tags: vb.net, oracle, visual-studio-2010, database-connection, oracle11g

Hey all i am trying to redistribute my app that uses Oracle 11g:

```
Imports Oracle.DataAccess.Client
```

The problem i am having is that it will not run on a machine that doesnt seem to have the correct drivers that its looking for. When i install **ODAC 11.2 Release 3 (11.2.0.2.1) with Oracle Developer Tools for Visual Studio** on the test VM it works just fine but thats a 230+mb file to download and install! Not to mention that if the user already has Oracle 10/11g on their machine that it **may** mess up their current connections/etc by installing that setup file.

Is there another setup package that i can install that only has the **Oracle Data Provider for .NET 2.0 11.2.0.2.0** or whatever its needing from that **ODAC 11.2 Release 3** file.

So any help about what i need to go about fixing this problem would be great! :)

Thanks,

David

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assuming you are on a 32bit environment you ought to be able to use the
    [ODAC112021Xcopy_32bit.zip 50.5 MB (53,019,552 bytes)](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/windows/downloads/utilsoft-087491.html)

the corresponding 64-bit 
    [ODAC112021Xcopy_x64.zip - 53.3 MB (55,955,853 bytes)](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/windows/downloads/index-090165.html)

the files are smaller than the ODT tools but they work.  Here is a dated (but it should get you on the correct track) [how-to](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2008/08-nov/o68odpnet-101744.html)

Comment: Awesome! Thanks there Harrison :o)